# CSS : Selecting next elements with specific class

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code and I'm searching a way to select the `span`'s elements identified by `class="selection"` only inside after a select element where id beginning with "cf-":

```
<select id="cf-1234567891322418287202826"></select>
<span class="select2 select2-container">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection"></span> // Apply CSS HERE
    </span>
</span>

<select id="cf-8298298876787346863834334"></select>
<span class="select2 select2-container">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection"></span> // Apply CSS HERE
    </span>
</span>

<select id="tu-656555"></select>
<span class="select2 select2-container">
    <span class="selection">
        <span class="select2-selection"></span> // DO NOT Apply CSS HERE
    </span>
</span>
```

I tried the following code without any result. Where is my mistake ?

```
select[id^="cf-"] + span.select2-selection {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: `select[id^="cf-"] + span.select2 .select2-selection` ?

Comment: or maybe `select[id^="cf-"] + * .select2-selection`

Comment: you select2-selection element has no content, that's why it width = 0. You need to set display property or width to this element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span.select2-selection` is not a sibling of `select[id^="cf-"]` so you need to change that selector into

```
select[id^="cf-"] + span span.select2-selection {
   ...
}
```

since you are trying to match a `span.select2-selection` which is a child of a `span` element which is a sibling of `select[id^="cf-"]`.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
[id*="cf-"] .selection{
 //css code here
}
```

additional info:

```
[id*="sometext"]
```

will select any element with id containing "sometext"

by putting a space after that you can specify a element within this element

doing .selection will select the element with class "selection" inside the element with id containing that tex